# jQuery-mobile and stale data in pages

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm just starting experimenting with jQuery and trying to apply it to a very simple CRUD app that consists of list, create, edit & show pages.

I've applied the jQuery-mobile markup conventions and everything looks very nice. However, I am confused about the problem of refreshing stale data. I understand that jQuery-mobile overrides links and form submission with AJAX to deliver a 'one-page app'. Again, this is working for me and all my `data-role="page"` stuff is loading and transitioning correctly.

What I don't understand is that when I modify data, (e.g. submit a form to create a new item then navigate back to the 'list' page) certain pages need to be refreshed from the server to pick up the modified data. What jQuery-mobile does is just re-display the previously loaded page which is now stale. Similarly, every time I re-visit the 'create page' to create another new item the form is still filled in from the previous submit as the page is not actually refreshing.

If this is something I need to script myself, that's fine but I'm curious that there doesn't seem to be any mention of what I would have thought was a common scenario in the jQuery-mobile docs. It feels like I must be missing something obvious. How are other people handling this?

Comment: AFAIK It's just working that way. JQM loads external pages to the current DOM and treats it as a kind of cache. Consider removing a page with id=some.html forcing a fresh download. Also - get JQM alpha3 if you're working with the old one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rel=external technique causes problems elsewhere e.g. you can't deploy a fullscreen ipad app that uses rel=external.

I had exactly the same problem.  I'm tinkering with some patches that were published [here](https://gist.github.com/881817)

I pasted the following just after my `<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` reference:

```
script type="text/javascript">

    $('div').live('pagehide', function(event, ui){
      var page = jQuery(event.target);
        //alert('point 6875654');
      if(page.attr('data-cache') == 'never'){
        //alert('removing jqm history page');
        page.remove();
      };
    });

    </script>
```

I then added the data-cache attribute as follows:

```
<div class="page" data-role="page" data-cache="never">
```

This seems to have helped a lot, although I still have some related issues around redirects to do with ASP.NET security.

Answer (score 2):

My solution for a similar problem was to add rel=external to pages that are updated dynamically. I wish there were a method to "re-cache" a page when dynamic content is added

Comment: Where are you placing this tag? I have a form submission and I've tried the button, form and page and nothing works.

Comment: Phil the rel=external refers a link element. Specifically the one that brings you to the page that has the dynamically updated content. Forms work differently than links. I'd start here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/docs-forms.html

Comment: This helped me with an issue I had using ASP.NET MVC3. I was trying to add a simple back link to a page that contained a form which used POST. When the link was clicked, it wouldn't "refresh" the page like I wanted. Adding rel="external" to the link fixed that issue. Thanks!